# AWS Terraform IAM user with assume role for S3 back end

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, assume-role

To store the Terraform state file in S3 bucket, I have used admin account credentials and configured. Now I have created IAM user and trying to use assume role. Assume role has the administrator policy attached.

I have tested this AIM user setup with `aws sts assume-role --role-arn` commands. I was able to get the token and using the token able access the S3 bucket using `aws s3 ls` command.

Now trying to use the IAM user access/secret key with assume role for terraform. when I run `terraform refresh` command its giving below errors.

**provider code:**

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-west-2"
  max_retries = 1
  assume_role {
    role_arn = var.assume_role_arn
  }

}
```

**Error**

```
 Error: Error acquiring the state lock
│
│ Error message: 2 errors occurred:
│       * AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:user/deploy is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource:
│ arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:table/terraform-state-lock
│       status code: 400, request id: CV4J3JN1LD0KPDGHAOA9UL13ONVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG
│       * AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:user/deploy is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource:
│ arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:xxxxxxxx:table/terraform-state-lock
│       status code: 400, request id: BISQQDU4659LLI3CEDP26T8RJ7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG
│
│
│
│ Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
│ by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try
│ again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
│ flag, but this is not recommended.
```

Why this is not working in Terraform How to fix this error?

Thanks
SR

Comment: The error indicates you don't have permissions to use dynamodb.

Comment: @Marcin  I have attached `Administrator` policy to the role, it should have the access to dynamodb and s3. Also when I run `terraform refresh -lock=false` command getting this message `Error: error loading state: AccessDenied: Access Denied`

Comment: Bu the error says its about a user, not role: `user/deploy`.

Comment: I can run the `aws sts assume-role --role-arn` command and export the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` and access/secret key `terraform refresh` command works. which means I think user setup is correct. only with terraform its not getting the session token.

Comment: @sfgroups You are using it on local env. It's using your key not the role. Btw, you can add the profile in backend block.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like it's even assuming the role, otherwise the error would show up as an `assumed-role/deploy identity`.

I'd suggest you try exporting the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` variables in the command line and then run Terraform again.

I tried this few days back using Terraform Cloud with the terraform user credentials there, which is not exactly your case, but it should behave in the same way.